# Why, on iOS, is glRenderbufferStorage appearing to fail?

Tags: ios, rendering, framebuffer, opengl-es-2.0

On an iOS device (iPad) I decided to change the storage for my renderbuffer from the CAEAGLLayer that backs the view to explicit storage via glRenderbufferStorage. Sadly, the following code fails to result in a valid FBO. Can someone please tell me what I missed?:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_framebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_framebuffer);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &m_colorbuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_colorbuffer);

GLsizei width  = (GLsizei)layer.bounds.size.width;
GLsizei height = (GLsizei)layer.bounds.size.height;
glRenderbufferStorage(m_colorbuffer, GL_RGBA8_OES, width, height);

glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_colorbuffer);
```

Note:
The layer size is valid and correct.
This is solid production working rendering code. The only change I am making is the line:

```
glRenderbufferStorage(...)
```

previously I did:

```
[m_context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:layer]
```

Comment: The correct answer is because you cannot replace `[context renderbufferStorage]` with a `glRenderbufferStorage(...)` call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument for `glRenderbufferStorage` should be `GL_RENDERBUFFER`, not `m_colorbuffer`.

(It will store in `m_colorbuffer` because that is what's bound to the `GL_RENDERBUFFER` target from the previous `glBindRenderbuffer` call)

Comment: Good catch. Got it. I am still baffled about how to get the results of what I render to this renderbuffer to be displayed. If I don't establish that linkage between my CAEAGLLayer and the renderbuffer I have no way of getting the pixels on the screen. What am I missing?!? Sigh...

Comment: You are catching the minor error, but the major error is __he cannot do this__, this approach is invalid.  `[context renderBufferStorage]` obviously does something else internally, because without it, rendering doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

in iOS, you cannot use `glRenderBufferStorage` to bind color attachment, you need to request the storage from `EAGLContext` on the view layer. Somewhere on your view code, you must use code similar to this:

```
// First Bind a Render Buffer
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_colorBuffer);
[context renderBufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER forDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*) self.layer];
```

You cannot avoid the second line as it's needed by iOS, this is the line you refer to "linkage" from renderbuffer to layer